# Comunicação entre camadas

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Tenho 3 camadas , BLL,DAL e o Projeto.
Na camada DAL está o ENTITY (automaticamente cria os GETs e SETs) e quero usar os GETs e SETs

Pois quando chega na camada projeto o valor e "0".

Talvez esteja meio confuso a pergunta mais no código da BLL e do PROJETO tem uma linha comentada que ajude para entender o problema

Camada DAL

```
namespace DAL
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class TabUsuario
{
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int PerfilId { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }

    public virtual TabPerfil TabPerfil { get; set; }
}
```

}

Camada BLL está a classe login

```
TabUsuario DALUsuario = new TabUsuario();

public void Login(string Usuario, string Password)
    {
        bool exite = db.TabUsuario.Any(m => m.Login == Usuario && m.Senha == Password && m.Status == true);
        if (exite == true)
        {
            //AQUI O VALOR PASSA NORMAL , O PerfilId FICA COM VALOR 1
            DALUsuario.PerfilId = db.TabUsuario.Where(m => m.Login == Usuario).Select(m => m.PerfilId).FirstOrDefault(); 
        }

        verificacao = exite;
    }
```

Camada Projeto tenho

```
TabUsuario DALUsuario = new TabUsuario();

if (Usuarios.Verificacao == true)
        {
            lblLogado.Visible = true;
            lblLogado.Text = "Logado com Sucesso.!";
            //AQUI O VALOR NÃO CHEGA , O PerfilId FICA COM VALOR 0
            Session.Add("PerfilUsuario", DALUsuario.PerfilId);
        }
```

Comment: você está dando um new no objeto DALUsuario quando entra no projeto, ai ele vai zerar tudo mesmo. vc tem que pegar esse cara por referência.

Comment: @DeRamon eu descobri isso mais não sei como fazer so sei usar o "new", ainda estou estudando o c# poderia me dizer, ou me passar a base que vou atras ? Obrigado.

Comment: levando em consideração que o objeto DALUsuario se torna membro da sua Camada BLL, na sua camada Projeto você precisa instanciar um objeto da Camada BLL, e acessar o DALUsuario. Algo do tipo TabUsuario  usuarioProjeto = ObjBll.DALUsuario;  Você consegue enxergar ele se for publico.

Comment: @DeRamon Obrigado. Agora entendi, fui um pouco mais na teoria caso alguém entre por esse erro .!

Comment: A razão é que você não pode usar uma variável de instância para inicializar um outro usando um inicializador de campo, porque a ordem de execução dos initialisers campo é indefinido.
Base: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property