# Duvidas Gets/Sets

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Meu projeto tenho 3 camadas, DAL, BLL, Projeto utilizo ASP.NET

Tenho uma pagina aspx no projeto, que tem textbox contendo novos valores para um update no banco.

Na classe DAL tenho entity que automaticamente criou GETs e SETs

Minha duvida e o seguinte como eu passo valores para a classe.

Pois sempre passei valores via get e set, mais aqui já esta esta utilizando o get.

```
DALUsuario.Nome = AQUI QUE GOSTARIA DE RECEBER O VALOR DO TEXTBOX
```

Classe para Update.

```
 public void AtualizarUsuario(int idUsuario)
    {
        TabUsuario DALUsuario = db.TabUsuario.Find(idUsuario);

        DALUsuario.Nome = "";
        DALUsuario.UsuarioId = "";
        DALUsuario.Senha = "";
        DALUsuario.Status = true;
        DALUsuario.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;
        db.Entry(DALUsuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Página ASPX

```
protected void btnEdiUsuario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BLLUsuario = Usuario.DALUsuario;
        BLLUsuario.Nome = txtNomeUsuario.Text;
        BLLUsuario.Email = txtEmailUsuario.Text;            
        ...
        Usuario.AtualizarUsuario(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Usuario"]));
    }
```

Comment: sua pergunta ficou muito vaga, não deu para entender o que você realmente deseja. vc quer usar os get/set? atualizar dados? recuperar valores da textbox? MVC ou WebForm?

Comment: @Dorathoto Obrigado pela primeira resposta editei a pergunta para melhor compreensão de todos, até mesmo de quem tiver essa duvida no futuro.

Comment: Melhorou muito, mas eu ainda não consigo ajudar, coloque um exemplo do que esta fazendo, da página, etc.

Comment: @Dorathoto Acabei resolvendo o problema, editei a pergunta com a resposta.

Comment: o correto seria vc responder sua própria pergunta e marcar-la como a correta. e não modificar a própria pergunta.

Comment: @Dorathoto Feito.! Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Comunicação entre camadas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114725/comunica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-entre-camadas)

Answer (score 2):

Recuperar valores de TextBox

```
var Valor = Request.Form["IdTexBox"];
```

Porém em **WebForm** Creio que seja o que está utilizando (aspx)

```
<asp:TextBox id="textBoxId" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
 var Valor = textBoxId.Text;
```

Em **MVC**

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
var Valor = form["IDTextBox"];
```

MVC recebendo a própria DALUsuario como objeto

```
public ActionResult Index(DALUsuario user)
{
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mais creio que como a formulação da pergunta estava confusa sua resposta não resolveu =\

Answer (score 0):

SOLUÇÂO

Passei um objeto com todos os dados respectivos

PÀG ASPX

protected void btnEdiUsuario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BLLUsuario = Usuario.DALUsuario;

```
    BLLUsuario.Nome = txtNomeUsuario.Text;
    BLLUsuario.Email = txtEmailUsuario.Text;         
    ...
```

Usuario.AtualizarUsuario(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Usuario"]), BLLUsuario);
    }
CLASSE

public void AtualizarUsuario(int idUsuario, TabUsuario objDALUsuario)
{
        TabUsuario DALUsuario = db.TabUsuario.Find(idUsuario); ;

```
    DALUsuario.Nome = objDALUsuario.Nome;
    DALUsuario.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;
    db.Entry(DALUsuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
```

}

Comment: marque esse resposta como como aceita tem um **V** verde ali perto, assim todos saberão que essa solução resolveu seu problema ;)